# Offsetting table values by using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table of data and would like to create a macro to offset the values in the table by x value.I was wondering if there is a way to quickly add/subtract x value to each cell. I know I can make a macro to add/subtract x cell by cell but I think that might take a lot of time. I would appreciate your help!

Comment: General policy here is to demonstrate some effort made on your behalf, otherwise you come across as somebody who is asking for people to do your work for you.  I suggest that you try recording a macro, this will get you acquainted with how quickly and easily it is to get started.  The community will help you with finishing up on your particular goal, but you should take those first steps yourself.  You'll find the community will be much more helpful in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use paste special.

```
Sub test()
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Dim x As Long: x = 1
        .Range("B1") = x: .Range("B1").Copy '~~> any anchor cell
        .Range("A1:A10").PasteSpecial , xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
        .Range("B1").ClearContents
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

So above assumes that A1:A10 contains your table. HTH.